# Efficient way to compare one small dictionary and one large dictionary based on matching keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am comparing two dictionaries:

Example dictionaries:

```
d1={('A','B'):{('C','D'),('E','F')},
    ('X','Z'):{('R','T')},
    ('D','EEE'):{('BBB','BBBB')}
    
    }

d2={('A','B'):{('J','K')},
    ('D','EEE'):{('VVVV','BBBB'),('EEEE','BBBB')}
    
    }
```

Here, I am using keys from dictionaries as ID and performing something like an inner join.

My approach was this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1, orient='index').T\
   .melt(var_name='id', value_name='value')\
   .dropna(subset=['value']).reset_index(drop=True) 
   
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2, orient='index').T\
   .melt(var_name='id', value_name='value')\
   .dropna(subset=['value']).reset_index(drop=True) 

result = pd.merge(df1, df2,on='id',how='inner')
```

Output:

```
         id      value_x       value_y
0    (A, B)       (E, F)        (J, K)
1    (A, B)       (C, D)        (J, K)
2  (D, EEE)  (BBB, BBBB)  (VVVV, BBBB)
3  (D, EEE)  (BBB, BBBB)  (EEEE, BBBB)
```

Possible dictionary output:

```
{('A','B'): {('E','F'),('J','K')},
 ('A','B'): {('C','D'),('J','K')},
 ('D','EEE'): {('BBB','BBBB'),('VVVV','BBBB')},
 ('D','EEE'): {('BBB','BBBB'),('EEEE','BBBB')},
}
```

However, the original large dictionary (dict1) contains over 100 million items, so the merging dataframes (from dictionaries) method is highly inefficient. The other dictionary (dict2) contains 10,000 items. My plan is to iterate the items in dict2 over dict1 so that less iterations are needed for the inner join. How do I improve this with other approaches? Maybe create three lists - id, value_x, and value_y to make the algorithm more efficient? Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to build a new dict with common keys only?

Comment: Are you sure that you do not want an inner join?

Comment: Yes, it is inner join. My bad. I was not thinking straight. But it is really slow.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for commenting. Yes!

Comment: Does anything change if you simply swap `df1` and `df2` in your `merge` call?

Comment: The order of the ID changed based on which dataframe I put first. I didn't keep track of time because I just let my computer run for the whole day. I will keep track of the time to test the difference in df1 and df2 orders. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I tested it on subsets. Putting the smaller dataframe at first did run significantly faster. The thing is I already did that for the original data.